# How to calculate the norm squared of a variable vector when using CVX in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I want to solve a convex optimization problem. I need to minimize `(1/2)*(||W||^2)`. And W is an variable vector. Here is also an a constraint: `y(i)*(transpose(W)*x(i)+b)>=1`. 
It is a problem that we need to use SVM to solve. So `Y=[1;1;1;-1;-1]`. b is also a variable vector and it is the intercept term. We need to find the optimal W and optimal b to make `(1/2)*(||W||^2)` minimum. x(i) is the point in the domain that we want to classify.

Here is what I have coded but it is wrong. It just does not work.

```
cvx_begin
    variables W(2, 1) b(5, 1)
    minimize( 0.5*(pow_cvx(norm(W, 2), 2, 2)) )
    subject to
        Y*(x*W+b) >= One
cvx_end
```

Comment: It is an CVX Optimization problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without giving code that reproduces your error message it is hard to guess the problem with CVX. But as a first hint you can modify the objective in your problem to

```
cvx_begin
    variables W(2, 1) b(5, 1)
    minimize( norm(W, 2) )
    subject to
        Y*(x*W+b) >= One
cvx_end
```

, this will give the same optimal solution. Your form of the objective `(1/2)*(||W||^2)` is often used in derivations to make the math easier to handle but you do not need this form for CVX. Otherwise you can write

```
cvx_begin
    variables W(2, 1) b(5, 1)
    minimize( 0.5*sum(W.*W) )
    subject to
        Y*(x*W+b) >= One
cvx_end
```